# Servo problem when use gps with softwareserial

Tags: arduino-mega

When I use together servo motor and gps module with softwareserial , I found problem .Servo turing without signal.When I remove gps receive pin ,servo normally work. I use arduino mega 2560, ublox NEO6M and micro servo SG90 .Help me please!

Comment: Why are you using SoftwareSerial on a board that has lots of UARTs? Ditch it - all your problems will be solved.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean why do you need to use SoftwareSerial? It is not good when doing anything else that relies on interrupts since it blocks the whole system when it's receiving a byte.  Just use the real hardware UARTs - that's what they're there for.